# PvP strategy for Through the Ages

Tags: through-the-ages

I recently purchased the Steam version of the board game so I apologize in advance if this is the wrong place to post my question.

I’ve been successful in winning vs the AIs; however, am struggling to keep afloat in PvP games online.

I understand there’s no one strategy to the game but it would help if I can get some beginner level tips to help me during the first few turns of the game.

My basic moves are to build one mine and one farm in the beginning to keep me from increasing my population and also to be able to complete either the Garden or the Pyramid.
But somehow I end up behind and constantly find myself playing catch-up to the other players

Should I just focus on one thing and not try to complete multiple things?
Also when I keep trying to stay above the corruption line, I find myself digging myself in a hole for some reason.

Any and all advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hey Josh! The question is a little too open-ended for the site. Using [this](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/15977) as a guide, try to ask a more specific question that is objectively answerable.

Comment: @Manath I'm a bit late here, but "objectively answerable" isn't really a requirement. We don't want things to be *primarily* opinion-based, but subjective questions that invite folks to justify their answers are fine. It looks like the issue here is more just that a lot of things are being asked at once.

Comment: @Cascabel That makes sense. I’ll phrase future comments accordingly.